# Compiling Tikz-PGF Manual

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to compile parts of the most to update version of the `Tikz-PGF` manual (3.0.1a) :

[Find the files here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/)

While trying to compile the first tutorial: A Picture for Karl's Students, I ran into some errors:

[image]

I don't know what the error message is about. The macros I imported from the file that Till Tantau put with the files.

Anyone have experience with this. Note the `\end{document}` in the image. I had to do this to get some pdf output.

I am trying to comply `.tex` files from the 'en-text folder'. You'll sind the preamble and body there along with everything else. Macros are in a separate folder.

[image]

Comment: I added the macro : `\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\textit{#1}\rangle$}` and it outputs that text as the manual. Now I am running into problems with command: `\verb!(30:1cm |- 0,0)!` in in the file and the text(p38 in the manual/tutorial). Not happy with how they set this up! :(

Comment: I do not know how to read your question. If I look on my computer for `pgfmanual.tex`, I get several hits, one for `pdflatex`, one for `lualatex` and so on, each of which lies in a separate directory and has hard coded relative paths. So I am wondering which file you're trying to compile, and in which directory.

Comment: I posted an image from the folder where I am pulling the files from 'en-text' folder. I am currently run into problems with \verb!(30:1cm |- 0,0)! in the programs Till has, but when I comply separating I get no errors. I looked at his macro but can not make sense of it.

Comment: I downloaded those files from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/

Comment: I have the first 10 pages of the the first tutorial and then I run it into the verbatim problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you since I do not work with these click-on-folder thingies but I am sure others do. (I work with terminals, which has the advantage that I always know where what gets compiled with which compiler, and I would guess that doing this will resolve the issue but for the above-mentioned reasons I cannot check.)

Comment: which documentclass are you using? the pgfmanual use ltxdoc which defines \meta.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I am using the article documentclass . I figured out the \meta problem to get the output to look like the manual. I am trying to run the files and reproduce the manual myself . Insert the macro below: \newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\textit{#1}\rangle$}. Now I am having trouble with the verbatim command in the program but not when I run separately so it must have to do with the macros Till Tantau wrote to be inserted?

Comment: @MathScholar the manual uses the ltxdoc class which define a number of commands for such manuals. If you want to use another class you will have to provide suitable definitions yourself.

Comment: Once I inserted that in the program everything worked. Thank you! Is there a way for me to compile the table of content separate? This appears before the tutorial.

Comment: I also noticed that the version compiling is 3.0.0 and not 3.0.1a. I downloaded the version on CTAN so it should be up-to-date. Any clues why I am getting this result?

Comment: +1 I have just asked to archive the old manuals and my request has been closed, so your question is now topical. [Archive old manuals? #903](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/903)